# Software recommendation for developing a mobile application (a little or no coding required)

Tags: android, cloud-service, mobile, iphone-app

I need a software that can be used to develop (using a little or no code) mobile application for help managing my family spendings. The software must falls into these criteria:

1. Little or no code involve as I don't want to learn Java or anything else apart from Python.
2. It supports building both iOS and android applications.
3. There is no vendor lock-in, which means if I am unsatisfactory with the service the software provided, I can export the raw data of the mobile application to files, then import these files into a new software (it's like flexibility).
4. It can export the mobile app as a file out when all the work is done, this allows the user to gain full ownership and use this file to upload to Window Store/Google Store/Apple Store.